# How to Resolve 'Canvas is not part of the THREE namespace' Error in React Three Fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm working on a project using React Three Fiber and have run into an issue when trying to integrate custom components. I'm receiving the following error message: Error: R3F: Canvas is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend? See: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/objects#using-3rd-party-objects-declaratively

This error occurs when I try to render my scene within a React component. Here is a simplified version of my setup:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import MyCustomComponent from './MyCustomComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <MyCustomComponent />
    </Canvas>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MyCustomComponent is supposed to be a simple 3D object added to the scene, but it seems like the Canvas component isn't recognized correctly.

What I've tried:

Ensuring that all dependencies are up to date.
Following the documentation on extending the THREE namespace, but I'm not sure I'm applying it correctly in the context of React Three Fiber.
Looking through similar issues on GitHub and StackOverflow, but none seem to match my specific problem.
Here is a link to a CodeSandbox that replicates the issue: [CodeSandbox Project Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/LuigiHard/EcoFunding/master?import=true&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsxmo0dd0002356k1v77f64n%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsxmo0dd0004356k646v3pik%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsxmo0dd0005356k47a9wqrn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsxmo0dd0002356k1v77f64n%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsxmo0dd0002356k1v77f64n%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsxmo0dd0005356k47a9wqrn%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253

I tried removing canvas , putting canvas on other files and many other stuff but still bugged